# random number that always makes a total of 100 into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i am trying to create an array that always has a total of 100 based on random numbers. I get it to work when there is 2 or 3 rows but i can't get it to work if there are more as 4. Meaning i need to change the middle section. Here is simple code i made: (the length is the number of rows in the array)

```
var array = []
var length = 3; //4 , 5 , 6 ...
var number;
var calculate;
var totalProcessed;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  // FIRST ONE
  if(i == 0){
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    console.log(number);
    totalProcessed = number;
    array.push(number)
  }
  //  MIDDLE SECTION
  if(i > 0 && i == length-1){
    if(length > 2){
      calculate = 100 - number;
      number = Math.floor(Math.random() * calculate) + 1 
      totalProcessed = totalProcessed + number;
      console.log(number);
      array.push(number)
    }
  }
  // LAST ONE
  if(i == length -1){    
    
       var lastOne = 100-totalProcessed;
       console.log(lastOne);
       array.push(lastOne)
    
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

How should i change the middle section to be able to capture the numbers?

Comment: how many item do you like to get?

Comment: variable (length), could be 4 but as well could be 13

Comment: What is the problem? You did not describe what is wrong... Now, certainly what I think looking at the code is: why do you have everything inside a `for` loop even though the first block only executes for `i==0` and the last for `i == length -1`? You should move the first block before the loop, the last block outside the loop and decrease the loop iterations by 2, and remove the condition on when to run the "middle" stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in this code:

**First**:

You should change the `==` to `<` in order to be able to loop more then 3 times:

```
if(i > 0 && i == length-1)
```

**Second:**

I think your error occurs on the following line. You subtract number from 100 which is the previous generated number. You should instead generate a random number from everything that is left:

```
calculate = 100 - number;
```

So I think you should subtract the totalProcessed value instead.

```
calculate = 100 - totalProcessed;
```

**Full working snippet:**

```js
var array = []
var length = 5; //4 , 5 , 6 ...
var number;
var calculate;
var totalProcessed;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  // FIRST ONE
  if(i == 0){
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    console.log(number);
    totalProcessed = number;
    array.push(number)
  }
  //  MIDDLE SECTION
  if(i > 0 && i < length-1){
    if(length > 2){
      calculate = 100 - totalProcessed;
      number = Math.floor(Math.random() * calculate) + 1 
      totalProcessed = totalProcessed + number;
      console.log(number);
      array.push(number)
    }
  }
  // LAST ONE
  if(i == length -1){    
    
       var lastOne = 100-totalProcessed;
       console.log(lastOne);
       array.push(lastOne)
    
  }
}
console.log(array);

let total = 0;
array.forEach(el => total += el)
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found your approach a bit hard to comprehend. Is the question setup same as what code is trying to do? Therefore I wrote an alternate example that solves the question (as currently explained):

```js
let limit = 100;
const numbers = [...Array(limit)].map(() => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  if (limit - random > 0) {
    limit -= random;
    return random;
  }
  
  return null;
}).concat(limit).filter((num) => num)

console.log(numbers);
```

It goes through 100 iterations (in case there would come only 1's :D) and then decreases the limit. And if next random number fits into limit, it's added to the result, otherwise it's a null.

And if it happens that after 100 iterations there are still limit left, it's concatenated to an existing array. Finally we filter out all the "nulls" (numbers that didn't fit in to limit) and voila.

Comment: it was simplefied cause i need to add sections to existing code. However, your version looks great but where do i find the length? It now also created random array length.

Comment: @EwaldBos oh, it's meant to have a certain maximum length for array items? E.g. three and then we keep getting random values until they match total with 100?

Comment: the length is a fixed number from an existing array, where i needed to add this section of code to to create the numbers, they array was here to make it work as a code example. Your version works perfect tho, just not easy to add to the existing code that is already there. Thanks for your time, input and approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the "==" in the if statement of the middle section by "<".

Comment: That's the meat of it. And remove the "-1" I daresay -- If I understand the code of the question correctly.